# I have an Object and I want seperate Object from given Object

Tags: javascript

```
const myjson = {
  "productname0": "Test1",
  "price0": "10",
  "categories0": "61",
  "type0": "Physical",
  "availability0": "available",
  "weight0": "0.5",
  "productname1": "Test2",
  "price1": "20",
  "categories1": "61",
  "type1": "Physical",
  "availability1": "available",
  "weight1": "0.7",
}
```

I have an Object and I want to separate object. All the key value which has last number 0 it has own json, for 1 it has own json.

I want this result

```
[{
  "productname0": "Test1",
  "price0": "10",
  "categories0": "61",
  "type0": "Physical",
  "availability0": "available",
  "weight0": "0.5",
},
{
  "productname1": "Test2",
  "price1": "20",
  "categories1": "61",
  "type1": "Physical",
  "availability1": "available",
  "weight1": "0.7",
}]
```

Comment: That is not JSON. Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: do you want to separate object into array( list of objects) based on last number?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: do you want to separate object into array( list of objects) based on last number? –

yes

Comment: The result you say you want is not valid syntax. Is there supposed to be an array there?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question.

Comment: See my answer , tell me if its helpful to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
const myjson = {
  "productname0": "Test1",
  "price0": "10",
  "categories0": "61",
  "type0": "Physical",
  "availability0": "available",
  "weight0": "0.5",
  "productname1": "Test2",
  "price1": "20",
  "categories1": "61",
  "type1": "Physical",
  "availability1": "available",
  "weight1": "0.7",
}

var finalArray=[];
Object.keys(myjson).forEach(function(value){
if(value.endsWith("0")){
    if(!finalArray[0]){
        finalArray[0]={};
    }
    finalArray[0][value]=myjson[value];
} else if(value.endsWith("1")) {
    if(!finalArray[1]){
        finalArray[1]={};
    }
    finalArray[1][value]=myjson[value];
}

});
console.log(finalArray);
```

Update :

```
const myjson = {
  "productname0": "Test1",
  "price0": "10",
  "categories0": "61",
  "type0": "Physical",
  "availability0": "available",
  "weight0": "0.5",
  "productname1": "Test2",
  "price1": "20",
  "categories1": "61",
  "type1": "Physical",
  "availability1": "available",
  "weight1": "0.7",
}

var finalArray=[];
Object.keys(myjson).forEach(function(value){

var lastChar = value[value.length -1];

    if(!finalArray[lastChar]){
        finalArray[lastChar]={};
    }
    finalArray[lastChar][value]=myjson[value];

});
console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: for each new you have to add logic! is that not fixed?

Comment: check my updated answer, anyway you have to use little logic to direct  correct position

Comment: if you are sure about that last character will be the integer always, then you can try my updated solution!

Comment: I don't think that you can assume that the index will be less than 10, i.e. a single character at the end

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have a working solution for you if you want to try it :

```
var Data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < (Object.keys(myjson).length) / 6; i++) 
{ 

Data.push({ 
"productname": myjson["productname" + i], 
"price": myjson["price" + i], 
"categories": myjson["categories" + i],
 "type": myjson["type" + i], 
"availability": myjson["availability" + i], 
"weight": myjson["weight" + i] 
}); 

}
console.log(Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this input :

```
const myJSON = {
  "productname0": "Test1",
  "price0": "10",
  "categories0": "61",
  "type0": "Physical",
  "availability0": "available",
  "weight0": "0.5",
  "productname1": "Test2",
  "price1": "20",
  "categories1": "61",
  "type1": "Physical",
  "availability1": "available",
  "weight1": "0.7",
}
```

You want to separate the properties according to the last character on the keys.

So you create an array containing your result, and them loop over the input's keys using `Object.keys`

For each key, separate the last character, because this will be your result index. Also check if the result array contains an object at that index already, or create an empty object if not.

Then you have this :

```
const result = [];

Object.keys(myJSON).forEach(key => {
    if (result[key[key.length-1]] === undefined) {
        result[key[key.length-1]] = {};
    }
    result[key[key.length-1]][key] = myJSON[key];
})
```

This solution will work for any input object, given that the keys / properties have the index at the end of their name.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `reduce` function, something like this:

```
const parameterNames = ['productname', 'price', 'categories', 'type', 'availability', 'weight'];
const data = Object.keys(myjson).reduce((acc, key) => {
  let parameterName = null;
  for (let i = 0; i < parameterNames.length; i++) {
      if (key.indexOf(parameterNames[i]) > -1) {
         parameterName = parameterNames[i];
         break;
      }
  }

  if (parameterName) {
    let index = key.split(parameterName)[1];

    if (acc[index] === undefined) {
      acc[index] = {};
    }

    acc[index][parameterName] = myjson[key];
  }    

  return acc;
}, []);
```